# How do I check if my hash has a key from an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

With Ruby, if I have a hash, what is the fastest way to check if it has a key from an array of strings?  So I could do this

```
has_key = false
arr_of_strings.each do |str|
    if my_hash.has_key?(str)
        has_key = true
        break
    end
end
```

But taht seems like way too many lines of code for such a simple inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
hash = {:a => 'apple', :b => 'bob', :d => 'thing'}

has_key = hash.keys.map(&:to_s) & strings  # ['a', 'b']
has_key.any? # true
```

a one-liner that's similar, `hash.keys.detect { |key| strings.include?(key.to_s) }.nil?`

Comment: Natalia, JFYI, this is not the _fastest_ way (which you, supposedly, wanted). :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm more bothered by the `.map(&:to_s)` making this *incorrect*. Even Josh's own example is judged differently by Natalia's code...

Comment: @StefanPochmann the symbol vs string debate is exhausting to me, too :(

Comment: @StefanPochmann: no, not always. It returns true when no keys are found in the hash.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh, right. Ruby keeps confusing me with its aliases and odd names. But that one-liner is still wrong, the result should be negated (unless it's ok to have the result negated, I guess).

Answer (score 5):

As simple as this:

```
arr_of_strings.any? {|s| my_hash.key?(s) }
```

Or, to get bonus points for clever-yet-less-readable code:

```
arr_of_strings.any?(&my_hash.method(:key?)) # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

To see if the array and the keys have any in common, you can use set intersection:

```
(arr & hash.keys).any?
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this works in this case because the array is an array of strings but not for example for `arr = [false]` and `hash = {false => true}`.

Comment: Who would do that? :)